# Compare users in different sheets and add user to sheet A if not present in A but present in B

Tags: excel, vba

We use an Excel file as a support tracker.  Our main sheet (A) has a list of users and their data.  For daily support, we run the MYSQL stored procedure to get the data, then paste it into a blank sheet (B) that colors and filters the data.

I am supposed to search the users in sheets A and B, and if a user is present in B but not A (scenario representing adding a user to our system) add the missing user to sheet A.

Based on my past programming knowledge, the steps should be:

- count rows in sheets A and B
  A has more data further down the sheet that is not raw user data, but it is in the same columns so looking for the first blank cell in A
- do a compare on those results
- if the results are different, do a vlookup to find the missing entry
- insert that entire row from sheet B to sheet A

I assume this can be done with VBA code.

Comment: What have you tried?, what columns contain the user names in both worksheets?

Comment: So at this point I spent a while googling to understand all the excel specific macros, and I have a simple script that excludes the header and counts the number of rows in separate sheets and displays the results in a msgbox.  Its a bit more complicated than just usernames.  Because I deal with PHI, I need to also take fill # into account to see if its the same person, different fill, or if its a new user entirely.  Im looking into appending the data into a worksheet and doing a matching thing, as well as figuring out if my way is viable. Just trying to figure out the best way to get this done

Answer (score 0):

You can write a VBA script to do this, and probably should if this is a regular process.

Alternatively a sorting approach will handle this and many similar problems. It works like this, given two sheets **A** & **B** with mixed duplicate and unique entries:

1. Append **B** to **A**
2. Sort by desired category (*User* in this case)

This will have duplicates (*User*) next to each other

3. Insert a match check column consisting of *If User EQ PreviousUser, True, False;*
4. Cut and paste **Values** to change from a function to simple content of True/False
5. Sort by *True/False* column
6. Delete the entire block of True's

Done!

This approach also works for more than two sheets. Append them all together, sort, mark dups, delete.